# Disable ui-select when selected list is empty -angular

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

How do I disable the selectbox of ui-select- multi select if there is no item to select

```
<ui-select
                                multiple  theme="bootstrap"
                                ng-model="categories.selected"
                                on-select="selectCategory($item,$model)">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Item...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices
                                    repeat="category in categories.categories track by category.id">
                                {{category.name}}
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ui-select` directive offers an `ng-disabled` attribute.

Example:

```
<ui-select
                                multiple  theme="bootstrap"
                                ng-model="categories.selected"
                                on-select="selectCategory($item,$model)"
                                ng-disabled="categories.categories.length === 0">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Item...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices
                                    repeat="category in categories.categories track by category.id">
                                {{category.name}}
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
```

Comment: The placeholder disappear when I change in that way @AranS

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `ng-disabled` to disable any component provided by Angular. Therefore here also you can use `ng-disabled` with `ui-select`.

```
<ui-select
                                multiple  theme="bootstrap"
                                ng-model="categories.selected"
                                ng-disabled="categories.selected.length === 0"
                                on-select="selectCategory($item,$model)">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Item...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices
                                    repeat="category in categories.categories track by category.id">
                                {{category.name}}
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
```

Comment: The placeholder disappear when I change it